# AWS EC2: Allowing specific users to run specific command

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, policy

I need to create an IAM policy so I can allow specific users to accomplish specific tasks like resetting IIS.

Comment: IAM is used for restricting access to the AWS API. IIS is a piece of software installed on your EC2 server. You do not manage IIS via the AWS API. I don't see how IAM could be used to restrict IIS permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Identity and Access Management (IAM) on AWS is used to manage permissions for using AWS services, such as launching Amazon EC2 instances, creating storage buckets in Amazon S3 and launching Amazon RDS database instances. Thus, it **controls how users can manage AWS Services**.

You are asking about controlling what users can do on a Windows machine. This is **out-of-scope of IAM** since it is managed by the operating system (Microsoft Windows).

Please consult **standard Microsoft Windows documentation** for information about how to manage Windows users and grant permissions them to perform tasks within Windows.